# Indirect speech in future

Tags: reported-speech

Can you please explain use of the future tense in this sentences:

> What time did Amy say she was coming?
> I think she said she will be coming at 8 o'clock

Why we use Past Perfect in the question and Future Tense in the answer

Comment: What is your understanding of “past perfect”? Where do you see it being used in those sentences?

Comment: Past tense. The saying is in the past, and the coming is in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Both question and answer are in the *simple past*.

The question is, "*What time **did** she say...*", and the answer is, "*She **said**...*".

If you're asking about the *reported speech* parts, it's a bit complicated.

To make it simpler, I'm using "Bella" for the person asking the question and the "Connor" for the person answering the question.

Some time before this conversation, Amy told Connor something like:

> I **will be coming** at 8 o'clock.

Bella wants to know what Amy said her plans were, so she asked Connor. Since the question is about plans, she used *present continuous for future plans* in her reported speech. Also, since it's reported speech, she *backshifted* the present continuous to *past continuous*, "*...she **was coming**?*".

When Connor reports what Amy said, he reports the tense that Amy used, and chooses not to backshift because it's optional when the speech being reported is still valid.

This means the reported speech in the question was in a future form, and so was the reported speech in the answer, so it's correct and natural.